# jqgrid post multi-level json

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I have a grid where the colmodel looks like:;

```
colModel:[ 
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:30, sorttype:'int'}, 
    {name:'name',index:'name', editable:true, width:200},
    {name:'group.id',index:'group.id', editable:true, width:200, formatter:'select', edittype: 'select'},
    {name:'sql',index:'sql', editable:true, width:100}
],
```

When I now edit the data and post it to the server the json looks like:

```
{"name":"Name 1","group.id":"1","sql":"sql","oper":"edit","id":"1"}
```

But my server expects a multi-level json like:

```
{"name":"Name 1","group":{"id":1},"sql":"sql","oper":"edit","id":"1"}
```

My serializeEditData looks like:

```
serializeEditData:function(data) {
    if (data.id === '_empty')
        data.id = null;
    return JSON.stringify(data)
}
```

Is there an elegant way to format javascript objects as multi-level json?

Answer (score 0):

if you start with, say

```
var jsobj =  {"name":"Name 1","group":"","sql":"sql","oper":"edit","id":"1"};
```

I think doing simply

```
jsobj["group"] = {"id" : 1}; 
console.log(jsobj);
```

should work and result in:

```
{"name":"Name 1","group":{"id":1},"sql":"sql","oper":"edit","id":"1"}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Here a very generic function [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794127/1381730). This is exactly what I looked for