# Can this flat (dot notation) to hierarchical object conversion be improved?

Tags: javascript, syntax, data-conversion

I am trying to convert a flat object in dot notation (like MongoDb uses for the updates) into a hierarchical one.

The input object for example is:

```
var flat = {
    "a": 123,
    "b.c": "234",
    "b.d.e": 345
}
```

The current conversion code is:

```
var obj = {};
var parent = obj;
Object.keys(flat).forEach(function(key) {
    var subkeys = key.split('.');
    var last = subkeys.pop();
    subkeys.forEach(function(subkey) {
        parent[subkey] = typeof parent[subkey] === 'undefined' ? {} : parent[subkey];
        parent = parent[subkey];
    });
    parent[last] = flat[key];
    parent = obj;
});
```

Is there a better way (JS trick) to do it?

Comment: _"IE8 does not support `Array.splice`"_ - Yes it does. But if you want to remove the last element `.pop()` makes more sense anyway.

Comment: ok, then it does not support with negative parameter (if I remember correctly) (cannot test it right now)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794127/1420197

Comment: related: [Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19098797/1048572)