# Dot notation object to multi-dimensional object

Tags: javascript

With the following data format:

```
const flat = {
    '100': 'L1',
    '100.200': 'L1, J2',
    '100.200.300': 'L1, J2, A3',
    '100.200.400': 'L1, J2, A4',
    '100.300': 'L1, J3',
    '100.400.500': 'L1, J4, A5'
};
```

I want to change it to something like this:

```
{
    "100":{
        "name":"L1",
        "children":{
            "200":{
                "name":"L1, J2",
                "children":{
                    "300":{
                        "name":"L1, J2, A3"
                    },
                    "400":{
                        "name":"L1, J2, A4"
                    }
                }
            },
            "300":{
                "name":"L1, J3"
            },
            "400":{
                "name":null,
                "children":{
                    "500":{
                        "name":"L1, J4, A5"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to implement some things from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793811/convert-javascript-dot-notation-object-to-nested-object) although they only cover a lot of my use cases and it's quite hard to figure out.

Comment: `Object.keys` to get all the keys from the flat object, `Array.map` with `String.split` to get parts of the object keys and `Array.reduce` to return the object you want

Comment: "*I've been trying to implement some things*" - please [edit] your question to include those attempts, otherwise we can't tell you what went wrong and will only be able to point you back to those existing questions about the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using an [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call on the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the supplied object.

```js
function expand(obj) {
  return Object
    .entries(obj)
    .reduce((a, [propString, name]) => {
      const
        propArr = propString.split('.'),
        innerProp = propArr.pop(),
        innerObj = propArr.reduce((_a, prop) => (
          _a[prop] ??= {}, _a[prop]), a);

      innerObj[innerProp] = { name };

      return a;
    }, {})
}

const flat = { '100': 'L1', '100.200': 'L1, J2', '100.200.300': 'L1, J2, A3', '100.200.400': 'L1, J2, A4', '100.300': 'L1, J3', '100.400.500': 'L1, J4, A5' };

console.log(expand(flat));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

But the question you linked, [Convert javascript dot notation object to nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793811/convert-javascript-dot-notation-object-to-nested-object), works just fine if you make a single change to accommodate the shape of your input.

```
target[parts[0]] = obj[objectPath]
```

becomes

```
target[parts[0]] = { name: obj[objectPath] }
```

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793811/convert-javascript-dot-notation-object-to-nested-object

function deepen(obj) {
  const result = {};

  // For each object path (property key) in the object
  for (const objectPath in obj) {
    // Split path into component parts
    const parts = objectPath.split('.');

    // Create sub-objects along path as needed
    let target = result;
    while (parts.length > 1) {
      const part = parts.shift();
      target = target[part] = target[part] || {};
    }

    // Set value at end of path
    target[parts[0]] = { name: obj[objectPath] }
  }

  return result;
}


const flat = { '100': 'L1', '100.200': 'L1, J2', '100.200.300': 'L1, J2, A3', '100.200.400': 'L1, J2, A4', '100.300': 'L1, J3', '100.400.500': 'L1, J4, A5' };

console.log(deepen(flat));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes total sense. Your expand function ended up failing when I put a super large dataset in but the second one worked great.