# Convert a string to a nested JavaScript object or JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string, data-conversion

I have the following string:

```js
let str = "modules.mas.mas-helper-provider.assets.locales";
```

and would like to convert it to a nested JavaScript  object (JSON), something like this result:

```json
{
  "modules": {
    "mas": {
      "mas-helper-provider": {
        "assets": {
          "locales": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also see: [Dot notation object to multi-dimensional object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67494499/dot-notation-object-to-multi-dimensional-object/67495055#67495055) which links to further duplicates including [Convert javascript dot notation object to nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793811/convert-javascript-dot-notation-object-to-nested-object)

Comment: And [Javascript: how to dynamically create nested objects using object names given by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484673/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-nested-objects-using-object-names-given-by) (since you can easily split your string to an array)

Answer (score 10):

You can split the string to an array, then [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to create an object by reading each key.

```js
let str = "modules.mas.mas-helper-provider.assets.locales";

var newObject = str.split(".").reduceRight((obj, next) => ({
  [next]: obj
}), "");

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how i can put another object in last {} ?

Comment: The second parameter of `reduceRight` as you can see is `""` as you had the empty string in the question. You can change it to whatever you want. In short, the first time `[next]: obj` is executed, you will assign to `locales` (your last key) the value specified. In this case `""`.

Comment: thank you really, I am still new with javascript